# Filter search results based on user field

Tags: views

I have previously created a view to search my different content types and it behaves like I want it to.

Now, I would like to limit the search results based on a user profile field. Each content type has an access level field. The access fields are tiered as follows:

A: every one can see it
B: only authenticated users can see it
C: only authenticated users with a certain profile property can see it

C users can see everything.
B users can see B and A content.

My first attempt at this was using a contextual filter and this sort of works. However, it only returns nodes that match the access tier.

I did this with PHP contextual filter code:

```
$memberAccessLevel = 'Public';

if (!empty($argument->field_membership['und'][0]['value'])) {
    $memberAccessLevel = $argument->field_membership['und'][0]['value'];
}

return $memberAccessLevel;
```

My question is, how can I set up the view so that tier C members can see all content?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. If my keys are A,B,C, I can return A+B+C to return all nodes marked with either A, B, or C. Basically, you need to concatenate the keys you want with + and that will achieve the desired effect.